# SETUP multiple sums with multiple date ranges

Tags: mysql, sum, conditional-aggregation

Here is the query I am trying to complete.

```
SELECT salesrep, 
    SUM(lines_total) AS OTSUM,
    SUM(order_type = 'NEW') OTNEW,
    SUM(order_type = 'REPEAT') OTREPEAT,
    SUM(lines_total 
      WHERE order_closed BETWEEN '2020-11-01' AND '2020-11-30') AS OTLMSUM
    SUM(lines_total 
      WHERE order_closed BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31') AS OTTMSUM
FROM `ranger_orders`
WHERE order_closed BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
```

Of course this fails, but how do I setup the SUMS for multiple date ranges, the WHERE date range at the end needs to stay as is.

For these lines:

```
SUM(lines_total WHERE order_closed BETWEEN '2020-11-01' AND '2020-11-30') AS OTLMSUM
SUM(lines_total WHERE order_closed BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31') AS OTTMSUM
```

Comment: If you don't know how to express a problem in code, then providing a narrative description of the result you are trying to achieve long with example inputs and outputs is a better idea than posting nonsense code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `CASE` expressions for conditional aggregation, like:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN order_closed BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31' THEN lines_total ELSE 0 END) AS OTTMSUM
```

For each of the sums, change `BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31'` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the data aligned on rows by salesrep, then you still need to add all the numbers - but you can substitute with zeroes where they are out of range....

```
SUM(IF (order_closed BETWEEN '2020-11-01' AND '2020-11-30', lines_total, 0)) AS OTLMSUM
```

You pointed out that you get a syntax error, but this looks like a semantic error:

```
SUM(order_type = 'NEW') OTNEW
```

Are you really trying to add these up? Count them? Classify them?

Query *might* be something like...

```
SELECT salesrep, 
    SUM(lines_total) AS OTSUM,
    SUM(IF(order_type = 'NEW', 1, 0)) OTNEW,
    SUM(IF(order_type = 'REPEAT', 1, 0)) OTREPEAT,
    SUM(IF (order_closed BETWEEN '2020-11-01' AND '2020-11-30', lines_total, 0)) AS OTLMSUM
    SUM(if(order_closed BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31', lines_total, 0)) AS OTTMSUM
FROM `ranger_orders`
WHERE order_closed BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
```

Also, with aggregate queries (SUM, AVERAGE, COUNT...) you should have a GROUP BY clause....

```
GROUP BY salesrep
```

However wouldn't it have been simpler to do this....

```
SELECT salesrep, 
    SUM(lines_total) AS OTSUM,
    SUM(IF(order_type = 'NEW', 1, 0)) AS OTNEW,
    SUM(IF(order_type = 'REPEAT', 1, 0)) AS OTREPEAT,
    DATE_FORMAT(order_closed, '%Y-%m') AS month,
    SUM(lines_total) AS otsum
FROM `ranger_orders`
WHERE order_closed BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
GROUP BY salesrep, DATE_FORMAT(order_closed, '%Y-%m')
```

Comment: `SUM(order_type = 'NEW')` is not a semantic error. It counts the number of rows where `order_type = 'NEW'`.

Comment: No it doesn't - you are relying on a side effect of MySQL interpreting a true boolean as '1' and an implicit cast to integer. The latter is a standard part of SQL-92 but rather innefficient. The former is not.

Comment: Yes it does. I am relying on a well documented feature of MySql for a requirement that is tagged MySql.

Comment: Reference please.

Comment: You already mentioned it: true is evaluated as 1 and false 0, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/boolean-literals.html

Comment: No - that's specifically MySQL - I said it was not part of SQL-92

Comment: All my comments are about MySql because the question is about MySql. You said that `SUM(order_type = 'NEW')` is a semantic error in code that runs in MySql. Well, it is not a semantic error. In other databases it would be a syntactical error. But not in MySql.